# How do I make an inner rounded rectangle and an outer rounded rectangle be parallel around the corners?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The outer radius does not follow the inner radius. I am currently using x = width/4 + radius + outset, y = height/4 + radius + outset. I think the outset needs to be some ratio of the hypotenuse.Please view my image on the link.

[rounded rectangle link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGvc1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make  the centers of the quarter-circles the same. This means that the radii must differ by the distance between the rectangles and the distances between the horizontal and vertical sides must be the same.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. I was adding the outset to the radius origin rather than to the radius.